# SAPUI5 this.getView() is undefined after calling the function from another controller

Tags: javascript, controller, sapui5, this

I have *TransformationConfiguration.controller.js* and *BaseRequest.js* where I want to outsource my fetch backend requests because of easier testing.

The problem is if *_getConfigList()* is called from the *deleteConfiguration* function in *BaseRequest.js* *this.getView().setModel(oModelConfigList, "ConfigList");* is not working as this.getView() is undefined. But if *_getConfigList()* is called in *onInit* everything works fine.

Another problem is, that *MessageToast.show(this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("successfulDeleted"));* is not working as this.getView() here is undefined, too.

Can someone offer me a solution please, I was trying to solve this problems for hours.
Thanks in advance!

TransformationConfiguration.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "com/transformationConfigurationUI/controller/BaseController",
  "com/transformationConfigurationUI/controller/BaseRequests",
  //...

], function (Controller, BaseRequests, MessageBox, MessageToast, FilterOperator, Filter, JSONModel, formatter, Sorter, sorter, CoreLibrary) {
  "use strict";
  var ValueState = CoreLibrary.ValueState;
  return Controller.extend("com.transformationConfigurationUI.controller.TransformationConfiguration", {
    formatter: formatter,

    onInit: function () {
      this._getConfigList(); // <-- works fine!
      //...
    },

    _getConfigList: function () {
      var oModelConfigList = new JSONModel();
      this.request = new BaseRequests();
      this.request.getAllConfigurations()
        .then(json => {
          oModelConfigList.setData(json);
        });
      this.getView().setModel(oModelConfigList, "ConfigList"); // if called from onInit works fine
//if called from that.request.deleteConfiguration(selectedConfigUuid); this.getView() is undefined!
    },

//...


onDelete: function (oEvent) {
      //create selected Config
      this._createSelectedConfigModel(oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent().getBindingContextPath());

      var oModelSelectedConfig = this.getView().getModel("SelectedConfig");
      var selectedConfigName = oModelSelectedConfig.getProperty("/name");
      var selectedConfigUuid = oModelSelectedConfig.getProperty("/uuid");
      var that = this;
      MessageBox.show(this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("deleteConfiguration", [selectedConfigName]), {
        id: "deleteWarningDialog",
        title: this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("delete"),
        icon: MessageBox.Icon.WARNING,
        actions: [MessageBox.Action.DELETE, MessageBox.Action.CANCEL],
        emphasizedAction: MessageBox.Action.DELETE,
        onClose: function (oAction) {
          if (oAction === MessageBox.Action.DELETE) {

            that.request.deleteConfiguration(selectedConfigUuid); //Problem here?
           
          } else {
            MessageToast.show(that.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("canceled"));
          }
        }
      });
    },


//...


_createSelectedConfigModel: function (configPath) {
      var oModelConfigList = this.getView().getModel("ConfigList");
      var oSelectedConfig = oModelConfigList.getProperty(configPath);
      var oSelectedConfigBrokenBinding = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oSelectedConfig));
      var oModelSelectedConfig = new JSONModel(oSelectedConfigBrokenBinding);
      this.getView().setModel(oModelSelectedConfig, "SelectedConfig");
    },

//...

  });
});
```

BaseRequest.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/base/ManagedObject",
  "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function (
  ManagedObject, MessageToast
) {
  "use strict";

  return ManagedObject.extend("com.transformationConfigurationUI.controller.BaseRequests", {

    getAllConfigurations: function () {
      return fetch("http://localhost:8080/transformations/ui/")
        .then(response => response.json());
    },

    deleteConfiguration: function (uuid) {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/transformations/" + uuid, {
        method: "DELETE"
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
           MessageToast.show(this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("successfulDeleted"));
          //this.getView() is undefined
          sap.ui.controller("com.transformationConfigurationUI.controller.TransformationConfiguration")._getConfigList(); //Problem here?
        } else {
           MessageToast.show(response.statusText);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You could pass a reference of your TransformationConfiguration.controller to the Baserequest constructor and use that reference to get the view.
Or you could bind the methods to your controller when calling them like `that.request.deleteConfiguration.call(that, uuid)`. But that looks kind of weird as it's already a member variable of the controller

Comment: @user1882585 Thanks, your approach with `that.request.deleteConfiguration.call(that, uuid)` was working, but I don't know if this is the best solution. Until now I was not able to pass a reference of the TransformationConfiguration.controller to the Baserequest constructor and use that reference to get the view. Do you have a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

for me it looks like you should read up more on delegate pattern before using it.

You have here basically 3 choices.

I assume that the first file is a controller and the delegate from `sap.ui.base.Object` or `sap/ui/base/ManagedObject`. Watch out for `onInit vs constructor`

1. pass a controller instance during new, hence you have a ref to the controller

```js
    onInit: function () {
          this._requestor = new BaseRequests(this);
          
    },
    onThat: function () {
          this._requestor.getAllConfigurations()
    },
    // should be in _requestor, here just for readability 
    constructor: function (controller) {
          this._controller = controller;
          
    },
    getAllConfigurations: (callback) {
         this._controller.doSomething()
    },
```

2. not very modern but still a js way. Pass a Callback

```js
    onInit: function () {
          this._requestor = new BaseRequests();      
    },
    onThat: function () {
         
         var doThatAfterwards = (result) =>{
           // this here points to the controller
          }
          this._requestor.getAllConfigurations(doThatAfterwards)
    },,
    // should be in _requestor, here just for readability 
    getAllConfigurations: (callback) {
         callback("myresult")
    },
```

3. use promises
   Promises can be created everywhere and even help you with sync/async stuff

```js
    onInit: function () {
          this._requestor = new BaseRequests();      
    },
    onThat: function () {
          this._requestor.getAllConfigurations.then((result) =>{
           // this here points to the controller
           // result contains 'foo'
          })
    },
    // should be in _requestor, here just for readability 
    getAllConfigurations: () {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           setTimeout(() => { resolve('foo'); }, 300);
     });
    },
```

Comment: If I pass a controller instance during new with `new BaseRequests(this);` I get a lot of Assertion failed. For example _ManagedObject.apply: encountered unknown setting 'mEventRegistry' for class 'com.transformationConfigurationUI.controller.BaseRequests' (value:'[object Object]')_

Comment: see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/19453962b8074b7399372c65cbe05370

Comment: Do you need to extend ManagedObject for your handler? Maybe `sap.ui.base.Object` is more approriate?

Comment: my guess, if you pass something without overwriting the constructor. you call the old one. I update my example. onInit is a controller lifecycle